Are Landau-Lifshitz equations equivalent to Hamilton's equations for classical spins?
Let $\boldsymbol{s}_1$ describe a "classical spin", i.e. a point on the surface of a unit sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It can be parametrized, for example, as
$$ \boldsymbol{s}_1 = \cos \phi_1 \cos \theta_1 \, \hat{\boldsymbol{x}} + \cos \phi_1 \sin \theta_1 \, \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} + \sin \phi_1 \, \hat{\boldsymbol{z}} \quad . $$
Now let $n$ of such spins interact through a Hamiltonian function $H(\boldsymbol{s})=H(\boldsymbol{s}_1,\boldsymbol{s}_2, \dots, \boldsymbol{s}_n)$.
The question in the title can be rewritten as: Is it always true that
$$ \dot{\boldsymbol{s}_i} = \boldsymbol{s}_i \times \nabla H(\boldsymbol{s}) \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \dot{\boldsymbol{s}_i} = \{ \boldsymbol{s}_i, H(\boldsymbol{s}) \} \quad ? \qquad (1) $$
Or, using yet another reformulation: Are Landau-Lifshitz equations equivalent to Hamilton's equations for a system whose phase space factors as product of $n$ unitary spheres?
I would very much like to understand this and perhaps prove equation (1) above, but my knowledge of classical mechanics on nontrivial manifolds is quite limited. I know that one can use the symplectic form on the sphere in order to write
$$ \{ f, g \} = \omega(X_f, X_g) \quad , \qquad \omega = \sum_{i=1}^n \sin \theta_i \, \mathrm{d}\phi_i \wedge \mathrm{d}\theta_i$$
which would give meaning to the Poisson bracket in (1) (at least away from the poles), but my computations do let me identify the cross-product in (1). I also don't really understand what is $X_f$, i.e. the Hamiltonian vector field associated to $f$, since now this thing is chart dependent.
I could find no papers on this, despite the massive amount of papers solving Landau-Lifshitz equations as if they were equivalent to classical equations of motion. I have the impression that, even if they are, this can only be true for Hamiltonians like
$$ H(\boldsymbol{s}) \sim \sum_{ij} J_{ij} \boldsymbol{s}_i \cdot \boldsymbol{s}_j \quad ,$$
but not general enough to cover, for instance, cases like
$$ H(\boldsymbol{s}) \sim \sum_{ijkl} J_{ijkl} (\boldsymbol{s}_i \cdot \boldsymbol{s}_j) (\boldsymbol{s}_k \cdot \boldsymbol{s}_l) \quad , $$
which cover e.g. the [overly hyped] SYK model.

To anyone interested: The answer is yes, and it is valid for any Hamiltonian function. If I have time (and no one answers the question correctly) I will post an answer.
